# NativeScript preview problems

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript and am checking it out to see if I can convert my Angular project to native. Unfortunately, I can't get it to preview anything. E.g., even a default Angular project created and converted to NS, like below throws errors on both my Android and iOS devices.

```
ng new Angular
cd Angular
ng add @nativescript/schematics
tns preview
```

The default project created with NativeScript directly (e.g., tns create NSAngular --ng) previews fine, so it is something to do with projects converted, looks like.

The errors vary and show up on both Linux (Fedora 29) and Windows (10), but they complain about missing app.component.html or not finding module "./" or something else. I can post the entire trace for one of those failures, if that helps, but I'm guessing (and hoping) this is a silly newbie error because even basic things are failing, and I would appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks!

Edit: Here are some logs.

LOG #1

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: Application entry point file not found. Please specify the file in package.json otherwise make sure the file index.js or bootstrap.js exists.\nIf using typescript make sure your entry point file is transpiled to javascript.
    at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:311)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:544)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./", relative to: app//
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
    at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:309)
    ... 12 more
```

LOG #2

```
2018-11-08 16:37:22.580 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] PlayLiveSync: applicationDidFinishLaunching

2018-11-08 16:37:22.592 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****

2018-11-08 16:37:22.592 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] Native stack trace:

1   0x105533f84 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool, bool)

2   0x105560fdc NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)

3   0x106039578 ffi_closure_SYSV_inner

4   0x10603c1b4 .Ldo_closure

5   0x233de0d14 <redacted>

6   0x233de0ce0 <redacted>

7   0x233de01d0 <redacted>

8   0x233ddfe7c <redacted>

9   0x233d581c0 <redacted>

10  0x233ddf908 _CFXNotificationPost

11  0x2347eeeb0 <redacted>

12  0x260c9d4fc <redacted>

13  0x260ca2e1c <redacted>

14  0x260543c18 <redacted>

15  0x26054c6f0 <redacted>

16  0x260543894 <redacted>

17  0x260544234 <redacted>

18  0x260542334 <redacted>

19  0x260541fe0 <redacted>

20  0x2605471a0 <redacted>

21  0x260548100 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext

22  0x260547058 <redacted>

23  0x26054bd9c <redacted>

24  0x260ca1314 <redacted>

25  0x26088cc34 <redacted>

26  0x2368a3890 <redacted>

27  0x2368ae658 <redacted>

28  0x2368add50 <redacted>

29  0x2338ac484 <redacted>

30  0x2338833f0 <redacted>

31  0x2368e2640 <redacted>

2018-11-08 16:37:22.596 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] JavaScript stack trace:

2018-11-08 16:37:22.596 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] 1   resolve@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:33:103

2   get@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:19:40

3   _fetch@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2465:50

4   _preParseTemplate@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2504:39

5   normalizeTemplate@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2492:57

6   loadDirectiveMetadata@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:10395:79

7   @file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23939:80

8   forEach@[native code]

9   @file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23938:83

10  forEach@[native code]

11  _loadModules@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23935:86

12  _compileModuleAndComponents@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23913:52

13  compileModuleAsync@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23873:68

14  bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4414:47

15  _bootstrapper@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:85:50

16  @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:148:32

17  notify@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:31

18  @[native code]

19  notifyAppStarted@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:140:36

20  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:132:30

21  @[native code]

22  onReceive@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:30:32

23  UIApplicationMain@[native code]

24  start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:273:26

25  run@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:301:10

26  bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:185:26

27  bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:103:38

28  bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:87:26

29  anonymous@file:///app/main.ns.js:10:57

30  evaluate@[native code]

31  moduleEvaluation@[native code]

32  promiseReactionJob@[native code]

2018-11-08 16:37:22.596 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] JavaScript error:

file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:33:103: JS ERROR Error: Could not resolve app.component.html. Looked for: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41C1E8E2-EC72-47F0-96A2-68C4A57AD22D/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/app.component.html.

2018-11-08 16:37:22.597 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception

2018-11-08 16:37:22.598 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] *** JavaScript call stack:

(

    0   UIApplicationMain@[native code]

    1   start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:273:26

    2   run@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:301:10

    3   bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:185:26

    4   bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:103:38

    5   bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:87:26

    6   anonymous@file:///app/main.ns.js:10:57

    7   evaluate@[native code]

    8   moduleEvaluation@:1:11

    9   promiseReactionJob@:1:11

)

2018-11-08 16:37:22.598 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not resolve app.component.html. Looked for: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41C1E8E2-EC72-47F0-96A2-68C4A57AD22D/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/app.component.html.

 at 

1   resolve@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:33:103

2   get@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:19:40

3   _fetch@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2465:50

4   _preParseTemplate@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2504:39

5   normalizeTemplate@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2492:57

6   loadDirectiveMetadata@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:10395:79

7   @file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23939:80

8   forEach@[native code]

9   @file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23938:83

10  forEach@[native code]

11  _loadModules@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23935:86

12  _compileModuleAndComponents@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23913:52

13  compileModuleAsync@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23873:68

14  bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4414:47

15  _bootstrapper@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:85:50

16  @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:148:32

17  notify@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:31

18  @[native code]

19  notifyAppStarted@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:140:36

20  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:132:30

21  @[native code]

22  onReceive@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:30:32

23  UIApplicationMain@[native code]

24  start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:273:26

25  run@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:301:10

26  bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:185:26

27  bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:103:38

28  bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:87:26

29  anonymous@file:///app/main.ns.js:10:57

30  evaluate@[native code]

31  moduleEvaluation@[native code]

32  promiseReactionJob@[native code]

', reason: '(null)'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x233e73ef8 0x233041a40 0x1055342d4 0x105560fdc 0x106039578 0x10603c1b4 0x233de0d14 0x233de0ce0 0x233de01d0 0x233ddfe7c 0x233d581c0 0x233ddf908 0x2347eeeb0 0x260c9d4fc 0x260ca2e1c 0x260543c18 0x26054c6f0 0x260543894 0x260544234 0x260542334 0x260541fe0 0x2605471a0 0x260548100 0x260547058 0x26054bd9c 0x260ca1314 0x26088cc34 0x2368a3890 0x2368ae658 0x2368add50 0x2338ac484 0x2338833f0 0x2368e2640 0x2368e22cc 0x2368e28e8 0x233e025b8 0x233e02538 0x233e01e1c 0x233dfcce8 0x233dfc5b8 0x236070584 0x260ca4bc8 0x10603c044 0x106038c8c 0x106038750 0x105501740 0x10603780c 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x10602f870 0x105e258d8 0x105df1940 0x105fc4c6c 0x105514414 0x105654f7c 0x1060376e8 0x106036bd0 0x106036bd0 0x10602f870 0x105e258d8 0x105df1940 0x105fc4dbc 0x10564c38c 0x10550ba80 0x10556c5a0 0x1052f0154 0x104d5b4f4 0x2338bcb94)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

2018-11-08 16:37:22.598 nsplaydev[5045:2029563] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
```

LOG #3

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 75, column: 14

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 75, column: 15
    Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 119, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 863, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 722, column: 14
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 75, column: 14

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 75, column: 15
    Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 119, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 863, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 722, column: 14
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Yes, please. Post the entire failure log, that might give us some clue.

Comment: Please see, if these instructions help you. https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

Comment: Thanks Manoj, I've added some traces. Baskar, my goal is to convert an existing Angular project to NS; creating a new one (at least with tns) works fine, but is not useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was add a --bundle flag to the preview call, as in:

```
tns preview --bundle
```

Thanks to the NS team who responded quickly to [my issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1640) - you will find other details there if you're interested, along with working code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create new, blank `tns` project somewhere aside and then compare your structure.

`19  notifyAppStarted@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:140:36`

can mean that file pointed in your `package.json` is not correct. Either it does not exists, or it is not in `.ts` format.

Could you provide your `package.json` content, where your main is defined and directory structure? We'd be able to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks, comparing was actually the first thing I did, replacing one/one in the failing one to see when it started working again. Unfortunately the errors I get keep changing, so it was difficult to pinpoint the issue without spending a ton of time. What's strange is that even the default Angular app doesn't work. I will try again later when I find time and report back if I find a fix.

Comment: have you solved it yet? I've just moved my project's structure from custom-undefined to the one from ng-template-blank and successfully adjusted all files. I'm a little bit more up-to-date with such migration, we can work on it together.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the offer. No, I didn't get a chance to work on it again, but will soon. If you're able to create a default Angular project and convert it to NS (like I explained in my original post), could you please outline how you did it? Perhaps I'm missing something basic, but all I can say is that the method described in the NS docs is NOT working for me.